# How to get a gap in x axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, graph, visualization

Is there some sort of function that allows this? I can't find anything.
The x axis I'm working with is characters not numeric.

For example, this y-axis but for the x-axis instead?
[image: example]

Comment: Try`ggbreak`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work for characters

Comment: Please provide a reproducible question (including data and code) to demonstrate the problem [Useful guidance for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Myabe `facet` + some custom theme can get you something similar